# Can I register my types in modules in Unity like I can in Autofac?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I am fairly familiar with Autofac and one feature that I really love about Autofac is the registering of modules.  Does anyone know how I can do this with Unity?  I'm having a hard time finding which terms to use in Google to come up with the unity equivalent if there is one.

```
public class Global : HttpApplication, IContainerProviderAccessor
{
   private static IContainerProvider _containerProvider;

   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
      builder.RegisterModule(new MyWebModule());

      _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
   }

[...]

   public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
   {
      get { return _containerProvider; }
   }
}

public class MyWebModule: Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
       builder.RegisterModule(new ApplicationModule());
       builder.RegisterModule(new DomainModule());
    }
}

public class ApplicationModule: Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
       builder.Register(c => new ProductPresenter(c.Resolve<IProductView>()))
                .As<ProductPresenter>()
                .ContainerScoped();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Just use Autofac or Windsor. You will find there's **a lot** missing in Unity and what's there works in unexpected ways. It's just not worth your time.

Comment: What specifically is missing in Unity? What does it do that is unexpected?

Answer (score 36):

Actually, you can do trivially with Unity container extensions.

```
public class Global : HttpApplication, IContainerProviderAccessor
{
   private static IContainerProvider _containerProvider;

   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      var container = new UnityContainer();
      container.AddNewExtension<MyWebModule>();

      _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(container);
   }

[...]

   public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
   {
      get { return _containerProvider; }
   }
}

public class MyWebModule : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Container.AddNewExtension<ApplicationModule>();
        Container.AddNewExtension<DomainModule>();
    }
}

public class ApplicationModule: UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<ProductPrensenter>(
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionFactory(c => new ProductPresenter(c.Resolve<IProductView>())));
    }
}
```